# How to multiply objects by specified rules?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, math

Let's say i want an object that when multiplied with, it multiplies by two and subtracts 1.
The syntax would look like this:

```
var a = {
    on_multiply: function(context){
        return context*2-1
    }
};
alert(2*a);
```

This would output 3.
I don't want to write
"a.on_multiply(2)"
Is there a way to do this?
If yes, is it possible to do this with arrays or matrixes also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to make the above example work is to assign a function named a, and have the context as a parameter of that function:

```
function a(context) {
    return (context * 2) - 1;
}
```

And if you really wanted a to be a function assigned to a name:

```
const a = context => 2 * context - 1;
```

And the above in ES5 syntax:

```
const a = functipn(context) {
    return (context * 2) - 1;
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I will try that!

Comment: That worked but is there a way to only write "2*a" rather than "a(2)"?

Comment: No, because you want 2 to be the context of the function, correct? This is the only way to pass data to a function if you want to use a variable value.

Comment: I want 2 to be in the context of the multiplication with a.

Comment: So, no then. You ***must*** pass 2 as a parameter to a, otherwise there is literally no way for a to receive 2.

Comment: Ok then, i will see what i can do!